# Get CSS transform value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get transform value with Jquery/Js, as below, 
**translate(22, 6) scale(1)**
I want to get 22 6 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var res = '';
    var str = $('.test').css('transform');
    var x = str.split(',');
    var len = x.length;
    res += parseInt(x[len-2]) + " " + parseInt(x[len-1]) + " " + parseInt(x[len-3]);
    alert(res);     
})
```

```css
.test {
    transform:translate(22px,6px) scale(1) ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"> my text</div>
```

Comment: thanks,but there is no 'px' in my string, it comes a 'NAN' by using your code.

Comment: translate values must have px.

Comment: Thanks again,I'll mark it,I get this transform by $('div').attr('transform'),and it has no 'px' unit,so could you help me to solve it in this situation.